# Pass a function to a tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I am printing tags that are related to a post and the result looks like the following:

```js
function getTag(){
  
  return "browse posts related to" + this.innerHTML;

}
```

```css
span, a{
  background: red; 
  color: #fff; 
  margin: 3px; 
  padding: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
Tags: <span title= 'getTag()'>
<a href="#"> food </a>
</span>

<span title= 'getTag()'>
<a href="#"> recipe </a>
</span>

<span title= 'getTag()'>
<a href="#"> drink </a>
</span>
```

I have tried passing the function `getTag()` to the attribute `title` but is not working correctly.

How do I use JavaScript to get the text content of each `span` element and pass the text content to the `title` attribute of each `span` element.

I will like using JavaScript to achieve this.

Comment: The title attribute is not an event..  So you cant do it that way.  If you want to get the text content of the a tag and place into the title atrribute then you coukd do this during page load.  i'm typing this on mobile so cant show a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any libraries, you need to work with the DOM. Place your script element at the bottom of the page.

```
<script>
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].title = 'browse posts related to ' + spans[i].innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

The script is easy to understand. You tell your browser to fetch all your span elements and store them inside the variable called spans. In the next step you can loop trough each of this spans and manipulate their attributes.